# Unexpected error with class-wp-hook.php on Wordpress

Tags: errors

I have my wordpress websites running for already a year or more. I have hosted two websites on `hostgator`. All of sudden, both of my websites shows same error.

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'WP_Maintenance_Mode' not found in /home1/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286

Can anybody please let me know how can I fix this problem.

Thanks... Any help is appreciated

Answer (score -1):

Somewhere in the theme, the `WP_Maintenance_Mode` class method is hooked to the filter or action. 
But when the hook is executed, this class doesn't exists or is not yet included.

I suspect that in the theme (file `functions.php`) this class is hooked to some event, but it is defined in an inactive plugin (I'm guessing it is ["WP Maintenance Mode"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-maintenance-mode/).)

Look for `add_action` and `add_filter` where this class is used as parameter.

```
add_action( 'some_action_name',  array('WP_Maintenance_Mode', 'method_name') );
add_action( 'some_action_name',  'WP_Maintenance_Mode::method_name' );
add_filter( 'some_filter_name',  array('WP_Maintenance_Mode', 'method_name') );
```

Try to comment out these lines or install the mentioned plugin and check if the warning disappears.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I looked on `functions.php` file but couldn't find `WP_Maintenance_Mode` in both `add_action` and `add_filter`. Also `WP_Maintenance_Mode` is not inside `functions.php` file.. Any other possible debug please :)

Comment: how do you know it is not a bug in the plugin itself?

Comment: So, if  the class `WP_Maintenance_Mode` is not used in the theme, then you will have to check the plugins.  
Turn off all active plugins and start activating one by one, watching when the warning appears.  
Then check this plugin.  @surazzarus